# Set dynamic images to Autogenerated columns in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

DataGrid is declared like that

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgDirectories" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

It is dynamically populated using `DgDirectories.ItemSource` property with `IEnumerable` of my DTO object. This object contains byte[] property with **dynamic** image (does not exist on HDD).
I want to **show** those **images in the grid**.

I've tried to convert `byte[]` to `BitmapImage` and pass it with data but anyway grid creates `DataGridTextColumn` for those type.

Probably this can be done much easier but I have a small experience using WPF...
Please help me to display images in column

P.S.: I'm newbie in WPF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Xaml code for dynamic pathname binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageFilePath}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

now just start your code behind logic with uri object instantiated with IEnumerable list of file paths...
Hope this would suffice

Comment: To be truth I haven't tried your code - I was able to redesign that part of the application to use datagrid with specified columns. But I'l mark your post as the answer - hope this work :). Does it work when grid will contain other columns rather than datetime?

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the autogeneratecolumn=true and specify the columns you want to show. This will give you the opportunity to specify the datatemplate of the column that has an image.

Comment: That's not going to work for me - I need to auto generate the columns because I am displaying several different kinds of objects in the grid. If I specify the columns, I can only do that for one type of object, and when the ItemsSource changes, the mapping won't work anymore. Is there a way i can specify multiple optional mappings, depending on the objects in the ItemsSource property?